# How do I prevent LoggerFactory.Create from throwing an exception when using Moq

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, moq

After some package/framework update (most likely Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection), one of my tests suddenly started throwing an exception from this line of code:

```
var userGetLogger = LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConfiguration(Configuration)).CreateLogger<UserGet>();
```

I am using Moq and the *Configuration* instance is created like this `new Mock<IConfiguration>().Object`

The reason for this approach is, that I  am calling one Azure Function from another in the same project, and need to conform to the UserGet's DI constructor signature and pass a logger of the correct type e.g. `(ILogger<UserGet> logger)` The code is being used in an Azure Function UserPost, where I need information from Azure Function UserGet. It works in production, but my test fails.The current workaround is to pass null to the UserPost constructor, do a null test, and then, if null, call LoggerFactory.Create(b => {}) (that does not throw an exception), but I hate this kind of "testing for test" code.

Is there any way to setup the Mock so this exception won't be thrown, and if not, is there a way I can test for the offending issue prior to throwing the exception?

Here is the internal MS exception stack trace. I'm afraid it's out of my mental jurisdiction to decipher it.

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.GetValue[T](IConfiguration configuration, String key, T defaultValue)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions.LoadDefaultConfigValues(LoggerFilterOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions.Configure(LoggerFilterOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.get_CurrentValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory..ctor(IEnumerable`1 providers, IOptionsMonitor`1 filterOption, IOptions`1 options)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.Create(Action`1 configure)
   at UserAccess.Functions.UserPost.<Run>d__10.MoveNext() in H:\Repos\EasySpect\Portal\UserAccess\Project\Functions\UserPost.cs:line 43
```

Here is a snippet of the UserGet class: (*GetUser() method excluded for brevity*)

```
public class UserGet
{
    IUsers Api { get; }

    ILogger Logger { get; }

    public UserGet(IUsers api, ILogger<UserGet> logger)
    {
        Api = api;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(UserGet))]
    public async Task<Guid> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "user/{email}")] HttpRequest req, string email)
    {
        if (email == null)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning("User email is not present in the URL");
            return Guid.Empty;
        }

        return await GetUser(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what `UserGet` looks like?

Comment: @beautifulcoder  Thx for the effort ;) Snippet added to question

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving `LoggerFactory` to the constructor. You really only need the `ILogger<UserGet>`.

```
public MyConstructor(ILogger<UserGet> logger)
{
  _logger = logger;
}
```

Then, you no longer need to `Create` a logger because it will already be available via private instance. This is also much easier to mock with Moq.

```cs
new Mock<ILogger<UserGet>>().Object();
```

Comment: The reason I am doing it this way is because I'm calling one Azure Function from another in the same project (runtime) so I need to pass an ILogger<UserGet> to the functions DI signature as per your example. The code is running in a function called UserPost, but I need info from UserGet. (I will make the question more specific)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the logger nullable and use

```
Logger?.LogWarning("Something");
```

etc

Then use an interface and wrapper for the logger factory, and just make it return null in your mocked version.

Comment: Yes. That's another, approach for a workaround, but still: I prefer to keep the production code completely indifferent to any testing context, and this would require even more workaround code than what I'm currently using